# How to change color of :after element after input:checked action?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with styling an `<input>` element. I want to change a color of :after content text to white after pressing the input.

How my page looks like rn:

[image]

```
<div class="x">
    <div class="z">
        <input type="radio" name="plec" class="plec" value="kobieta" <?=(isset($_POST['plec']) && $_POST['plec'] == 'kobieta') ? 'checked' : ''?>/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="y">
        <input type="radio" placeholder="mężczyzna" style="margin-left:5px;"  name="plec"  class="plec" value="mezczyzna" <?=(isset($_POST['plec']) && $_POST['plec'] == 'mezczyzna') ? 'checked' : ''?>/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.x{
    display: flex;
}
.z:after{
    content: "Woman";
    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:25%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 20px;
    color:rgb(117,117,117);
    pointer-events:none;
}
.y:after{
    content: "Man";
    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:75%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 20px;
    color:rgb(117,117,117);
    pointer-events:none;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + .y:after{
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I simplyfied your example and added a label instead of an after element.

Your code will not work, because CSS can't traverse up in the tree (look at the parent).

[Info about the `+` selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)

```css
.x {
  display: flex;
}
.x input {
  display: none;
}

label{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgb(117, 117, 117);
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}
.x input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <div class="z">
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" checked>
    <label for="female">Women</label>
  </div>

  <div class="y">
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender">
    <label for="male">Man</label>
   </div>
 </div>
```